# How to make source path dynamic

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I'm new in flex.Here is my problem:

```
<mx:HorizontalList id="horizontalList" height="100" columnCount="6" dataProvider="{arr}">               
 <mx:itemRenderer>
  <mx:Component>
    <mx:Image width="100" height="100" source="../../user/mahedi/weeding/album/{data}"/>
  </mx:Component>
 </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:HorizontalList>
```

I want to make source path dynamic.I mean I collected `userName` and `albumName` from php and I could print in flex. But when I use in source like this this way: 
`source="../../user/{userName}/{albumName}/album/{data}`
I found an error. How can I solve that please help me.

Comment: source="../../user/{userName}/{albumName}/album/{data}" when i set this path the builder give message access of undifined property userName and same for other.Have any solution

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
source="{'../../user/' + username + '/' + albumName + '/album/' + data}"
```

Comment: source="{'../../user/' + username + '/' + albumName + '/album/' + data}".when i set this path the builder also give message access of undifined property userName and same for other.Have any solution

Comment: That is because userName is a variable. You need to declare it in your code and assign it a proper value.

[Bindable] public var userName:String = "Mahedi";